# AngularJS: How to export ui-grid data to excel with custom HTML?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, export-to-excel, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

related to this link:

[AngularJS: How to export ui-grid data to excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40265774/angularjs-how-to-export-ui-grid-data-to-excel)

I like this answer but if I have a custom HTMl in grid for example chart :

> https://plnkr.co/edit/irskqERheTOiFql82QFC?p=preview

```
  $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs = [
    { field:'name' },
    { field:'gender' },
    { field: 'spark', cellTemplate: 'sparkline-cell.html', width: 100 }
  ];
```

how can I export this cells to Excel.